# maven not generating complete source

Tags: rest, maven, xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation

I am generating java sources from an xsd, in the generated sources I seem to be missing some annotations.

Example XSD

```
<xsd:complexType name="Test">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Value">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:minLength value="1" />
                    <xsd:maxLength value="3" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I expected to see in the java

```
public class Foo implements Serializable
{
    @XmlElement (required = true)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max =3)
    private String value;
```

When I generate using maven the java does not include the restrictions, just the basic values @XmlElement (required = true) then the member name

Am am missing an argument when generating, I'm stumped.

Comment: XJC does not generate JSR-303 annotations

Comment: @Xstian, Sorry for only adding the comment now, this is not what I was hoping to hear but after further research you are correct. Thanks.

Comment: you could apply an XSD validation during marshal and unmarshal at runtime.